# Servicestack AutoQuery not filtering results

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

my query
/API/Json/GetJson?Desc=test1

I get all records not just the test1 records

```
[Route("/API/Json/GetJson", "GET")]
public class GetJson : QueryDb<JsonModel>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? RefId { get; set; }
    public int? SecondRefId { get; set; }
    public int? ThirdRefId { get; set; }
    public int? FourthRefId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string JSON { get; set; }
    public string JsonType { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int? AuditId { get; set; }
}

public class JsonModel
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [IgnoreOnUpdate]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Other tables the this data is relevant to
    /// </summary>
    public int? RefId { get; set; }
    public int? SecondRefId { get; set; }
    public int? ThirdRefId { get; set; }
    public int? FourthRefId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// name that is displayed to users
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string JSON { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Tells what data type the JSON is storing
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string JsonType { get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public DateTime AuditStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

also my return data has extra fields. Starting at Skip

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "refId": 9,
    "secondRefId": 3,
    "thirdRefId": 100,
    "fourthRefId": null,
    "name": "test",
    "json": "JSON STRING DATA",
    "jsonType": "test",
    "desc": "test3",
    "auditId": 0,
**"skip": null,
"take": null,
"orderBy": null,
"orderByDesc": null,
"include": null,
"fields": null,
"meta": null**
},
```

I updated my model to nullables and its is till returing all records. My seed data and I am using SS 5.6.0

```
WireUpService<IntegrationService>();

    using (var db = HostContext.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
    {
        string JSON = " \"Columns\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"CompanyName\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"name\": \"Company Name\",\r\n            \"Visible\": \"True\",\r\n            \"Sort\": \"U,A,Z[Unsorted, A-Z, Z-A]\",\r\n            \"Filter\": \"Test Company\"\r\n          }\r\n        ],\r\n        \"ParentCompnay\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"name\": \"Company Name\",\r\n            \"Visible\": \"True\",\r\n            \"Sort\": \"U,A,Z[Unsorted, A-Z, Z-A]\",\r\n            \"Filter\": \"Test Company\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }";
        db.DropAndCreateTable<JsonModel>();
        db.Insert(new JsonModel { Desc = "test",Name = "test",JsonType = "test", JSON = JSON,RefId = 10,SecondRefId = 3, AuditId = 0, AuditStamp = DateTime.Now });
        db.Insert(new JsonModel { Desc = "test1", Name = "test", JsonType = "test", JSON = JSON, RefId = 10, SecondRefId = 3, AuditId = 0, AuditStamp = DateTime.Now });
        db.Insert(new JsonModel { Desc = "test2", Name = "test", JsonType = "test", JSON = JSON, RefId = 5, SecondRefId = 3, AuditId = 0, AuditStamp = DateTime.Now });
        db.Insert(new JsonModel { Desc = "test3", Name = "test", JsonType = "test", JSON = JSON, RefId = 9, SecondRefId = 3,ThirdRefId = 100, AuditId = 0, AuditStamp = DateTime.Now });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this issue using the classes provided, which I've seeded with **test data that matches the query** and **non-matching test data** that you've included in your JSON response:

```
db.CreateTable<JsonModel>();
db.Insert(new JsonModel { RefId = 1, SecondRefId = 1, ThirdRefId = 111, Name = "test1", Desc = "test1", JsonType = "test", JSON = "TEST1"});
db.Insert(new JsonModel { RefId = 9, SecondRefId = 3, ThirdRefId = 100, Name = "test1", Desc = "test3", JsonType = "test", JSON = "JSON STRING DATA"});
```

There is an issue with your `GetJson` model where you've specified `Id` and `AuditId` as non-nullable `int` properties which if not specified are populated in your `GetJson` Request DTO as `0` (default int).

If you're going to include required value types on your `GetJson` AutoQuery Service you should always be providing values for them otherwise change them into `int?` so they're not added to the query filter when they're not specified, e.g:

```
public class GetJson : QueryDb<JsonModel>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? AuditId { get; set; }
}
```

After doing this, it works as expected where I can query the Auto Query Service using your specified query, i.e:

```
var url = baseUrl.CombineWith("/API/Json/GetJson").AddQueryParam("Desc", "test1");
var json = url.GetJsonFromUrl();
json.Print();
```

Which works as expected returning the matching result in a `QueryResponse<T>` DTO, i.e:

```
{"Offset":0,"Total":0,"Results":[{"Id":1,"RefId":1,"SecondRefId":1,"ThirdRefId":111,"Name":"test1","JSON":"TEST1","JsonType":"test","Desc":"test1","AuditId":0,"AuditStamp":"\/Date(1577190306230-0000)\/"}],"Meta":{}}
```

Comment: updated my sample with my test data added nullables. still not working for me

Comment: @SteveColeman please provide a stand-alone project on GitHub I can run locally that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Project created and added you as contrib. Search for DemisUnitTest.  Thanks and Have a Very Merry Christmas or whatever Holiday you are celebrating!

Comment: This won't work for you because of the SQL server has an IP firewall. hmm let me see if I can make it work with inmemorysql

Comment: Chnages comitted,  It is running in memory sql, so it should work. Build and run the web service project profile as In Memory DB. then run the unit test - DemisUnitTest.Demis

Comment: @SteveColeman Please only provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in future, i.e. the issue isolated in a minimal repro, if you did this you would've likely discovered the issue yourself: This is not an AutoQuery Service this is implemented by your custom `List<GetJson> Get(GetJson request)` Service which just returns the full `GetJson` table without any filters if you added a filter e.g. `Db.From<JsonModel>().Where(x => x.Desc == request.Desc)` it returns the expected filtered results.

Comment: yep, i didn't understand how the routing was working. Thank you for helping me understand this.